# Unable to create passwordless SSH connection between Windows PC and Pi

Tags: ssh, raspbian-jessie

I am trying to use Wing Pro to debug a Python script on the RPi 3Bv1.2 (with Raspbian Jessie) and I have followed these instructions in order to create a passwordless SSH connection with my Windows PC (using plink/Putty):

http://wingware.com/doc/proj/ssh-setup-details

I have tried several times, copying both the id_rsa.pub and the copy-pasted text (in a file called key.txt) to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys but whatever I do I still get prompted for a password when I try to acces the RPi.

I have also followed another guide and added the following lines to the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file:

```
UsePAM no
PermitRootLogin no
AllowUsers pi
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

And I even disabled PasswordAuthentication but then I just get this message from plink:

*FATAL ERROR: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)*

Do you have any idea about what I am doing wrong?

Edit: I'n not sure which version of the public key I should copy to authorized_keys (I tried both), as there are guides indication both options:
a) the id_rsa.pub with format:
    ---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
    Comment: "rsa-key-20170428"
    (key)
    ---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY 
b) the copy-pasted text generated by puttygen with format:
    ssh-rsa (key) rsa-key-20170428

Edit 2: I logged the output of plink when trying to connect with PasswordAuthentication no. I hope this helps:

https://pastebin.com/hHbufjTU

Comment: All you should have to do is copy the public key to authorized_keys. No one can tell you any more, because you **haven't told us what you did** (don't paste links to tutorials and expect people to guess what you did). The least you could do is list the **exact** commands you tried and the **exact** error message.

Comment: Try using `ssh -vv` when you connect (if that's the client you are using).

Comment: What I did is basically create the /home/pi/.ssh folder and inside a file called authorized_keys containing the public keys.

    pscp openssh.pub username@remotehost:.ssh/pub.tmp
    plink username@remotehost "cat .ssh/pub.tmp >> .ssh/authorized_keys; rm .ssh/pub.tmp"

There is no error message to share as all that happens is that I keep getting asked for a password.

goldilocks: I am using plink (Putty), it doesn't have that option, nor can I give that parameter to Wing Pro

Comment: Commands:

    plink username@remotehost "mkdir .ssh; chmod 700 .ssh"
    plink username@remotehost "sed -i -e '$a\' .ssh/authorized_keys"
    pscp openssh.pub username@remotehost:.ssh/pub.tmp
    plink username@remotehost "cat .ssh/pub.tmp >> .ssh/authorized_keys; rm .ssh/pub.tmp"

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve this thanks to the wonderful guide by Walkernews:

http://www.walkernews.net/2009/03/22/how-to-fix-server-refused-our-key-error-that-caused-by-putty-generated-rsa-public-key/

Finally what did the trick after hours of experimenting was to change the permissions of my home folder to 755 (was 775)

Answer (score 1):

Look at Sudar's contribution to this post:
[Logging using SSH key for password less login is not working in Raspbmc](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8933/logging-using-ssh-key-for-password-less-login-is-not-working-in-raspbmc?rq=1)

I learnt the hard way, that a line feed or not can make all the difference in the authorized_keys file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).